# Finding an independent subset

Tags: linear-algebra

Find a linearly independent subset of the set: $(4,1,-3,2), (-2,3,4,0), (3,-1,2,0), (1,2,-5,2)$. Is there only one?

I have reduced the matrix to rref. Will the pivotcolumns be my independent subset?

Comment: If you form a matrix with those vectors as its columns, then do row reduction, the columns of the original matrix that correspond to pivot columns in the reduced matrix will be linearly independent (and so will any subset of this set of columns).

Answer (score 1):

(4,1,-3,2)=(3,-1,2,0)+(1,2,-5,2)

$\{ (-2,3,4,0), (3,-1,2,0), (1,2,-5,2)
\}$ will be independend tohgethre

becuase system of

$-2c_1+3c_2+c_3=0$

$3c_1-c_2+2c_3=0$

$4c_1+2c_2-5c_3=0$

$2c_3=0$

has only 0 as it's answer!

and every sub set of it will be independence too it has $2^3$ subset